# TypeError: y.indexOf is not a function

Tags: javascript

Tengo un array con objetos que incluyen las keys; title, authors y rating. Quiero buscar el primer objeto donde el valor de title comience con la letra 'A'

```
const books = [{
  title: 'Good Omens',
  authors: ['Terry Pratchett', 'Neil Gainman'],
  rating: 4.25
},
{
  title: 'Bone: The Complete Edition',
  authors: ['Jeff Smithh'],
  rating: 4.42
},
{
  title: 'American Gods',
  authors: ['Neil Gainman'],
  rating: 4.11
},
{
  title: 'A Gentleman in Moscow',
  authors: ['Amor Towles'],
  rating: 4.36
}
]

const titleA = books.find(y => y.indexOf('A') === 0);
```

Y obtengo este error:

```
TypeError: y.indexOf is not a function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu código esta parcialmente bien salvo estos detalles:

- El método indexOf no parece ser la mejor opción para filtrar por la coincidencia de un caracter al incio o fin de una cadena, recomiendo te [documentes a detalle sobre su uso aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/indexOf)
- Para el punto anterior luce como mejor opción una expresión regular, donde buscaremos que el caracter `A` esté presente al inicio de la cadena con `^[caracter]`
- Por otro lado aunque tienes un array, este por dentro esta compuesto de N objetos, dado eso tienes que hacer la sintaxis de: `book.propiedad` que para este ejemplo sería `book.title` que es de donde extraeremos los valores para buscar la existencia del patrón
- Con un condicional evalúas si la regex se cumple y en concencuencia retornas al
  objeto que muestre todos los datos del libro

Código:

```js
    const books = [{
      title: 'Good Omens',
      authors: ['Terry Pratchett', 'Neil Gainman'],
      rating: 4.25
    },
    {
      title: 'Bone: The Complete Edition',
      authors: ['Jeff Smithh'],
      rating: 4.42
    },
    {
      title: 'American Gods',
      authors: ['Neil Gainman'],
      rating: 4.11
    },
    {
      title: 'A Gentleman in Moscow',
      authors: ['Amor Towles'],
      rating: 4.36
    }
    ]
    
    const encontrado = books.find(book =>  {
      if (/^[A]/.test(book.title)) {
        return book
      } else {
        return 0
      }
    })
    
    
    console.log(encontrado);
```

Ya nadamas como *extra* lo podemos reducir a una línea sustituyendo nuestro if regular por el uso de un condicional ternario:

```
const encontrado = books.find(book => (/^[A]/.test(book.title)) ? book : 0)
```

- Enlace de interés [método `test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp/test)

Comment: ¿Que hay con .test? ¿Es un método disponible en RegeX? Saludos

Comment: si @g.4 aqui puedes leer mas al respecto https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp/test